# Core Data or NSDictionary with multiple date entries (about 800+ each year)? What would be the most easy to implement?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I'm trying to figure the best approach to solve this problem.

--

I have a "**History**" table that,
lists **ALL years** that have data.

If a user clicks a given Year, it segues to a new Table and,
lists **ALL months** that have data.

Clicking a given month, shows a new table that,
lists **ALL days** that have data.

Clicking a specific day, shows a list of one or multiple Time Stamps.

--

What is the best approach to solve this?

If user creates a Time Stamp. I need to insert it with today's date.

I also need to have the ability that if a user,
Deletes a given year. Everything in that year is deleted.

That same way,
Deleting a month, deletes everything in that month, for it's particular year.

And so on, to the point where the user should be able to delete Individual Time Stamps.

--

I thought I would Use a **Dictionary** with key for the "year". 2012, 2013, ...

And each retrieving another Dictionary with key for the "month", 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

And so on ... and so on ...

I also thought I could make a model using Core Data.

A Class Year representing the "**Year**" entity, having a relation to many possible **Months**, and each month, having a relation to many possible **days**, and days to **Time** **Stamps**.

And last,

I thought of creating a model with only two Entities.

**Entries**, with  only one attribute "**Date**", that has a **to-many relationship** to "**Time Stamps**", receiving All the possible Time Stamps for that given day.

I am new to iOS programming. So this is all theory for me. But I did follow some Core Data tutorials and others working with NSDictionaries, protocols delegates and so on.

The "Dig In" approach as I go trough, seems more elegant. Specially because I think I could delete a particular given object in a cascade manner?

Do any of these make sense? Or is there a more obvious easy way to go about it? Also, please consider in the answer **what would be easier to implement** if a user chooses to delete a given entry in the "tree"

Any help is most appreciated.

Thank you advance!

Nuno

Comment: Reading and writing a whole dictionary is easier. But when its in memory its going to get bigger and bigger. So use Core Data, SQLite, and just load what you need.

Comment: Going with Core Data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to rely on Core Data or any database engine, the best way to solve this is to use the database itself.

I see two possible solutions (there is more of course). The first, the simplest :

```
Entity
- timestamp
- year
- month
- day
- all_the_stuff_you_need
```

Make year, month and day readonly, updated along timestamp. Indexes: year, year+month, year+month+day. Easy call.

That way, you can very simple query the database, asking it to return the entities you need and only the entities you need.

A more complex setup would be:

```
Entity
- timestamp
- all_the_stuff_you_need
- year -> Year
- month -> Month
- day -> Day

Year
- year
- entities ->> Entity

Month
- month
- entities ->> Entity

Day
- day
- entities ->> Entity
```

So basically, 3 data domains for the years, months and days, months and days being immutable.

That structure is more complex, but it gives a better view of your data. You have a direct access to more information on your data as the data domains are explicit and well defined.

A third solution would be to create a date entity with year, month and day, with one entry per day. A middle ground between the two solutions above. Less interesting I think, but hey, it may suit your needs anyway.

Comment: I started with the easiest one with only one Entity. But I might just change to 3 data domains because for now I'm doing a fetch request. And it retrieves everything! I doesn't seem right? I think I can retrieve everything just once, then pass an object with Month, then one with Day, for each controller as I go through. Do you have any recommendations for it? Thank you so much for your help! Appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to fetch only the entities you are interested in with a simple predicate like `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"year = %x AND month = %x", year, month]`. No?

Comment: lol, ok. So try this: `NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new]; fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Entity" inManagedObjectContext: … ]; fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"year = %x", year];` and keep going.